# SQL Sum of last X Sum of records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've looked for a while and I cannot find the answer to this question (maybe I'm not searching the correct terms or something). Basically, I have a database that has any number of entries per date. I need to take the sum of the last X days that contain entries (ignoring days that have no entries). I know how find the sums for each day.

Say I have a table called "Yield":

```
UnitID  Date        TestTime    NumMeasured NumPassing
1       2013-04-05  10:15       25          3
2       2013-03-31  10:12       30          1
3       2013-03-30  10:12       26          2
4       2013-03-29  10:30       11          1
5       2013-03-31  10:20       6           2
6       2013-04-05  10:30       5           0
```

I then use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Date, 
    (
        SELECT SUM([NumMeasured]) 
        FROM [dbo].[Yield] T1 
        WHERE T1.Date = T2.Date
    ) AS 'NumMeasured', 
    (
        SELECT SUM([NumPassing]) 
        FROM [dbo].[Yield] T1 
        WHERE T1.Date = T2.Date
    ) AS 'NumPassing' 
FROM [dbo].[Yield] T2
```

To obtain the total passing/measured per day:

```
Date        NumMeasured NumPassing
2013-03-29      11          1
2013-03-30      26          2
2013-03-31      36          3
2013-04-05      30          3
```

I would then need a query that I could call on a date (say I call it for 4/05) that gets the last X(say 100) days that contain entries and returns the sum of the NumMeasured and the NumPassing columns for that many days. I cannot get this part to work, I keep running into SQL issues that I don't have enough experience with to solve. I am looking for something like

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 SUM(T3.[NumMeasured]) 
        FROM T3 
        WHERE T3.Date <= '4/05/2013' 
        ORDER BY T3.Date
    ) AS 'NumMeasured', 
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 SUM(T3.[NumPassing]) 
        FROM T3 
        WHERE T3.Date <= '4/05/2013' 
        ORDER BY T3.Date
    ) AS 'NumPassing', 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            Date, 
            (
                SELECT SUM([NumMeasured]) 
                FROM [PhaseNoiseMonitoring].[dbo].[Yield] T1 
                WHERE T1.Date = T2.Date
            ) AS 'NumMeasured', 
            (
                SELECT SUM([NumPassing]) 
                FROM [PhaseNoiseMonitoring].[dbo].[Yield] T1 
                WHERE T1.Date = T2.Date
            ) AS 'NumPassing' 
        FROM [PhaseNoiseMonitoring].[dbo].[Yield] T2 
    )
AS T3
```

The expected query would return:

```
NumMeasured NumPassing
103         9
```

I realize this is completely wrong, but I can't really figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, seems to me a "GROUP BY" clause could simplify your life a lot.

Comment: so you need sums for the last 100 dates.. not necessarily sums on dates within 100 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea using correlated subqueries:

```
with bydays as (<your query here>)
select bd.*,
       (select sum(NumMeasured) from (select top 100 * from bydays bd2 where bd2.date <= bd.date order by date desc) t
       ) as Measured100,
       (select sum(NumPassingd) from (select top 100 * from bydays bd2 where bd2.date <= bd.date order by date desc) t
       ) as Measured100
from bydays
```

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I needed (aside from the few typos), appreciate the speedy response, I haven't really used correlated subqueries before, but this seems much easier than the stuff I was getting into.

Comment: @Gordon-Linoff  What about when you need to aggregate across multiple values (i.e. group by say by UnitID in Matt's example above)?

Answer (score 0):

To get your last 100 dates,

```
SELECT TOP(100) DISTINCT date FROM yield ORDER BY date desc
```

You can simplify your first query with something as simple as

```
SELECT date, SUM(passing) as numpassing, SUM(Measured) as nummeasured
FROM yield
GROUP BY date
```

If you need the sum from now until 100 days ago

```
SELECT SUM(passing) as npassing, SUM(measured) as nmeasured
FROM yield
WHERE date >= DATEADD(d,100,CURRENT)
```

And if you need the sum from the last 100 dates

```
SELECT SUM(passing) as npassing, SUM(measured) as nmeasured
FROM yield
WHERE date IN (SELECT TOP 100 date FROM yield WHERE date <= '04/05/2013' ORDER BY date desc)
```