# Calculate Sum From Moving 4 Rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

I've have the following data.

```
   WM_Week  POS_Store_Count POS_Qty POS_Sales   POS_Cost
   ------   --------------- ------  --------    --------
   201541   3965            77722   153904.67   102593.04
   201542   3952            77866   154219.66   102783.12
   201543   3951            70690   139967.06   94724.60
   201544   3958            70773   140131.41   95543.55
   201545   3958            76623   151739.31   103441.05
   201546   3956            73236   145016.54   98868.60
   201547   3939            64317   127368.62   86827.95
   201548   3927            60762   120309.32   82028.70
```

I need to write a SQL query to get the last four weeks of data, and their last four weeks summed for each of the following columns: `POS_Store_Count`,`POS_Qty`,`POS_Sales`, and `POS_Cost`.

For example, if I wanted 201548's data it would contain 201548, 201547, 201546, and 201545's.

The sum of 201547 would contain 201547, 201546, 201545, and 201544.

The query should return 4 rows when ran successfully.

How would I formulate a recursive query to do this? Is there something easier than recursive to do this?

Edit: The version is Azure Sql DW with version number 12.0.2000.
Edit2: The four rows that should be returned would have the sum of the columns from itself and it's three earlier weeks.

For example, if I wanted the figures for 201548 it would return the following:

```
WM_Week POS_Store_Count POS_Qty  POS_Sales   POS_Cost
------  --------------- -------  --------    --------
201548  15780           274938   544433.79   371166.3
```

Which is the sum of the four (non-identity) columns from `201548`, `201547`, `201546`, and `201545`.

Comment: What query have you tried so far?

Comment: What are you trying to `sum`? You probably can do this with a very basic query using `top`, `where` and `order by desc`...

Comment: @sgeddes My apologies, I'm trying to sum the `POS_Store_Count`, `POS_Qty`, `POS_Sales`, and `POS_Cost` columns. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Love2Learn Azure Sql Data Warehouse. It appears as if the version is 12.0.2000.

Comment: I'm confused as to what the four rows should be? If you want a sum wouldn't you want one row with four columns for the target week and the three weeks before it? Do you want it to be consecutive so if we wanted week 8 and the values for week 5, 6, 7, and 8 were 1, 2, 3 and 4... would you want a single value of 10 or values of 1, 3, 6, 10?

Comment: @Love2Learn I'll update the question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Look at JamieD77's answer. It will give you all the information you're asking for for each week and then you can just filter down the results.

Comment: @Cameron, your question is self-contradicting. You are saying that you want 4 rows returned, but when you give an example there is only one. So which is that you want, one or four?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Sum of last X Sum of records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067105/sql-sum-of-last-x-sum-of-records)

Comment: @zespri I wouldn't say it's self-contradicting, but over-simplified rather. I'm trying to provide the MVC in order to make my point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty sure this will get you what you want.. Im using cross apply after ordering the data to apply the SUMS

```
Create  Table #WeeklyData (WM_Week Int, POS_Store_Count Int, POS_Qty Int, POS_Sales Money, POS_Cost Money)

Insert #WeeklyData Values
(201541,3965,77722,153904.67,102593.04),
(201542,3952,77866,154219.66,102783.12),
(201543,3951,70690,139967.06,94724.6),
(201544,3958,70773,140131.41,95543.55),
(201545,3958,76623,151739.31,103441.05),
(201546,3956,73236,145016.54,98868.6),
(201547,3939,64317,127368.62,86827.95),
(201548,3927,60762,120309.32,82028.7)

DECLARE @StartWeek INT = 201548;
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [WM_Week] DESC) rn
    FROM #WeeklyData 
    WHERE WM_Week BETWEEN @StartWeek - 9 AND @StartWeek  
)
SELECT *
FROM cte c1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(POS_Store_Count) POS_Store_Count_SUM, 
                    SUM(POS_Qty) POS_Qty_SUM, 
                    SUM(POS_Sales) POS_Sales_SUM,
                    SUM(POS_Cost) POS_Cost_SUM
             FROM   cte c2 
             WHERE  c2.rn BETWEEN c1.rn AND (c1.rn + 3)
) ca     
WHERE c1.rn <= 4
```

Comment: I think this is what you want. @JamieD77 took everything into consideration. I added the records so you could test it with the supplied inputs since I had at least done that much. :)

Comment: @Love2Learn thanks!.. Sql fiddle is not working for me right now for some reason or I would have shown my work there

Comment: Awesome! This is pretty much what I was looking for. The only issue now is that I actually have 15 more columns or so that I need to integrate into it. And the performance of the query is awful. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: You can try using a temp table instead of a CTE.. that might speed it up some.. I wouldnt think it'd be that slow only selecting 9 rows though..

Comment: @JamieD77 Well.. I was slightly wrong on my requirements in my question, but I was able to adapt your answer to my needs. My table is a data warehouse table, so we don't have indices. We do, however, have partitions by that WM_Week column. We ended up removing the Row Number column, and just used that WM_Week. It returns 53k rows in under 6 seconds, compared to the same row count in 19 minutes.

Comment: @Cameron  glad you got it working.. I'd still consider using a temp table instead of a CTE, especially in correlated sub queries, which is what a cross apply basically is.  Unless you removed the CTE all together which would also be better :)

Comment: We are actually using this as a view, so using a temp table is not an option. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: ahh gotcha.. that explains the speed issue then since you can filter by `WM_Week` using a param..  this might be a good case for proc if possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUM()` in combination with the [OVER Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Something like:

```
SELECT WM_Week.
, SUM(POS_Store_Count) OVER (ORDER BY WM_Week ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a SQL window function for this.

Add a column to your query like the following:

```
SUM(POS_Sales) OVER(
   ORDER BY WM_Week 
   ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
) AS POS_Sales_4_Weeks
```

Comment: What dialect is this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't want to return 4 rows, but rather 4 summed columns for each group?  If so, here's one option:

```
select max(WM_Week) as WM_Week,
       sum(POS_Store_Count),
       sum(POS_Qty),
       sum(POS_Sales),
       sum(POS_Cost)
from (select top 4 *
      from yourtable
      where wm_week <= 201548
      order by wm_week desc) t
```

This uses a subquery with `top` to get the 4 rows you want to aggregate based on the `where` criteria and `order by` clause.

---

Here is a condensed [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36a986/2) demonstrating the example (sorry fiddle isn't supporting sql server right now, so the syntax is slightly off):